# Kentico ASCX transformation page type properties

Tags: kentico

I'm starting to plan out an full dynamic accordion. The idea is files would be upload to a series of folders. Now i could place a bunch of repeaters on a page, one per folder and have a transformation that reads the files and generates links and the HTML for the accordion. What I'm hoping to do is have one transformation what will read all the folders, and their children.

So initial logic is something like this.

```
if (PageType = cms.Folder && HasChildren = true){
  Output folder name + html
  Output children + html
}
```

Example content tree:

parent node

- Folder 1

  - PDF
  - PDF
  - PDF
- Folder 2
- Folder 3
- Folder 4

I can control the children page types, cms.file, and the parents will be cms.folder, but how do i detect determine the actual page type and if there are children?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mark, consider using [hierarchical transformation](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K8/Using+hierarchical+transformations)/viewer - it should handle this.

Comment: Is the an good tutorial on using these? I tend to figure things out easier follow something like that.

Comment: Sure: https://docs.kentico.com/display/K8/Using+hierarchical+transformations , https://devnet.kentico.com/articles/how-to-build-up-a-menu-using-the-hierarchical-transformation , http://devnet.kentico.com/articles/best-practices-for-implementing-site-navigation-in-kentico

Comment: Thanks. I'm starting to plan this out. I'll post a new question if/when i run into problems.

Answer (score -1):

We can use nested repeater in transformation. Something
Reference link is
https://devnet.kentico.com/forums/f67/t42585/repeater-nested-in-transformation

Comment: //--------- transformation-------------------

<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="CMS.DocumentEngine" %>`

<script runat="server" type="text/javascript">

  protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e) {
  nestedRPT.Path=Eval("NodeAliasPath") + "/%";
  nestedRPT.ReloadData(true);
}
</script>

<%# Eval("DocumentName")%> 

<cms:CMSRepeater
ID="nestedRPT"`enter code here`
DelayedLoading="true"
runat="server"
TransformationName="cms.file.YourTransformationName"
ClassNames="cms.file"
ZeroRowsText="Nobody"
/>