# Kentico hierarchical transformation and a bootstrap accordion

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, kentico

This is a continuation of this question: [Kentico ASCX transformation page type properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40218365/kentico-ascx-transformation-page-type-properties)

A quick over view. The end goal is a Bootstrap based accordion, where i can show a link and description for uploaded files that are group.

In the CMS.Desk, i have the parent node ( a page, CMS.MenuItem). I then have child pages, which are the groups. The files (pdf, word, ppt, etc), will up uploaded and not attached.

So, the resulting code would be like this.

```html
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">

    <div class="panel panel-default">

        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading1">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse1">
                    Group One
                </a>
            </h4>
        </div>

        <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading1">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <a href='#'>Link to Document</a>  
                    <p>Document subscription</p>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href='#'>Link to Document</a>  
                    <p>Document subscription</p>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href='#'>Link to Document</a>  
                    <p>Document subscription</p>
                  </li>                  
                <ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="panel panel-default">

        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading2">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse2">
                    Group Two
                </a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading2">
            <div class="panel-body">
                                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <a href='#'>Link to Document</a>  
                    <p>Document subscription</p>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href='#'>Link to Document</a>  
                    <p>Document subscription</p>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href='#'>Link to Document</a>  
                    <p>Document subscription</p>
                  </li>                  
                <ul>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    

</div>
```

My header transformation would be this (all level 0):

```html
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
```

my footer transformation (all level 0):

```html
</div>
```

Each panel has an open and closing div, then the panel header and panel body.

So, my panel header, is my first child page, while my panel body is the links and descriptions of the uploaded files.

I think for here, i would need a sub heading, and sub footer for the open and closing divs (both level 1), but the heading and body i'm not sure about.

Would be panel heading be level 3, and my panel body be level 4, and what type of tranformations would they be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have just two levels there: panel heading and panel body.

Level 0 header:

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
```

Level 0 item transformation:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">

    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading1">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse1">
                Group One
            </a>
        </h4>
    </div>

    <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading1">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <ul>
              {^SubLevelPlaceHolder^}                  
            <ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Level 1 item transformation:

```
              <li>
                <a href='#'>Link to Document</a>  
                <p>Document subscription</p>
              </li>
```

Level 0 footer:

```
</div>
```

This is not the only configuration for your hierarchical transformation, it is just one of many possible approaches.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It does. The levels were confusing me. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Roman. I've got this working. 4 ASCX transformations and it's fine. I'm going to add other items out side of the scope of this question. Cheers!